# How does one use python as a submission script using the PBS scheduler?

Tags: pbs

I’ve used python as my submission script in the past rather than bash etc. In slurm conder I usually instructed the path of the compiler at the top. I tried it in `qsub` but it didn’t work. Any idea how to make it work?

Code:

```
#/homes/miranda9/.conda/envs/myenv/lib/python3.7
#PBS -V
#PBS -M me@gmail.com
#PBS -m abe

import sys

for p in sys.path:
    print(p)
```

then I did:

```
qsub test_qsub.py
```

error msg:

```
$ cat test_qsub.py.e381299 
/homes/miranda9/.profile: line 2: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpivars.sh: No such file or directory
/homes/miranda9/.profile: line 3: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/bin/compilervars.sh: No such file or directory
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/369.
/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/381299.iam-pbs.SC: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `print'
/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/381299.iam-pbs.SC: line 9: `    print(p)'
```

---

after I added `!` and made '#!/homes/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7' at the top I got a new error:

```
$ cat test_qsub.py.e381301 
/homes/miranda9/.profile: line 2: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpivars.sh: No such file or directory
/homes/miranda9/.profile: line 3: /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017/linux/bin/compilervars.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: /var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/381301.iam-pbs.SC: /homes/miranda9/.conda/envs/automl-meta-learning/lib/python3.7: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

---

crossposted:

- https://community.openpbs.org/t/how-does-one-use-python-as-a-submission-script-using-the-pbs-scheduler/2271
- [How does one use python as a submission script using the PBS scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63891078/how-does-one-use-python-as-a-submission-script-using-the-pbs-scheduler)
- https://qr.ae/pNFW6P
- https://www.reddit.com/r/HPC/comments/issqbu/how_does_one_use_python_as_a_submission_script/

Answer (score 0):

First don't forget the `!` at the top.

The trick is to figure out where the binary for python is (with your conda environment for example) and tell PBS at the top for your submission script. I tried using `sys.path` but that lead to a path to a folder that PBS couldn't use. I had to find out the `sys.executable` to find it. Then I just put it at the top.

Demo session to find it:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/homes/miranda9/.conda/envs/myenv/bin/python'
```

then place it properly with the exclamation mark:

```
#!/homes/miranda9/.conda/envs/YOURENV/bin/python
#PBS -V
#PBS -M youremail@gmail.com
#PBS -m abe
#PBS -lselect=1:ncpus=112

import sys
import os

for p in sys.path:
    print(p)

print(os.environ)
```

works now!